# Let $S=[0,1) \cup [2,3]$ and $f:S \to \Bbb R$ be a strictly increasing map such that $f(S)$ is connected. Which of the following statements is true?

Tags: functions, continuity, problem-solving, connectedness, monotone-functions

> 1. $f$ has exactly one discontinuity.
> 2. $f$ has exactly two discontinuities.
> 3. $f$ has infinitely many discontinuities.
> 4. $f$ is continuous.

I know theorems related to connectedness and continuity but I don't seem to incorporate them here in solving the problem. Can you suggest me how to approach this problem?

Comment: I recommend starting by understanding some examples: can you think of any $f$ from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which are strictly increasing and have connected range?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay I can construct. Like $$f(x)= \begin{cases} x, & \text{ x $\in$ [0,1)} \\ x-1, & \text{ x $\in$ [2,3]} \end{cases}$$.So this will be continuous.

Comment: Now check the number of discontinuities for the function you formed.

Comment: @Albas Oh! This function is discontinuous at $x=1$ and $x=2$.

Comment: But the function is not defined for $1$

Comment: @Albas Hmm right. :( $1$ is not in the domain. So $x=2$ is the only discontinuity?

Comment: Yes. $x=2$ is the only discontinuity

Comment: @Albas Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that this $f$ is continuous. Take a $\xi\in S\setminus\{1,2\}$. Assume that $$\sigma:=\sup_{x\in S, \>x<\xi}f(x)<f(\xi)\ .$$ Then there is an $\eta$ with $\sigma<\eta<f(\xi)$. It follows that $f(S)$ can be partitioned into the two relatively open sets $f(S)\cap{\mathbb R}_{<\eta}$ and $f(S)\cap{\mathbb R}_{>\eta}$, contradicting the assumption about $f(S)$. It follows that in fact $$\sigma=f(\xi)\ .$$ (The same argument also shows that $\sup_{x\in S, \>x<1}f(x)=f(2)$, but this is not relevant for the continuity of $f$.)

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there is an $x_0<\xi$ with 
$$f(\xi)-\epsilon=\sigma-\epsilon<f(x_0)<f(x)<f(\xi)\qquad(x_0<x<\xi)\ .$$
As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary this proves $\lim_{x\to \xi-} f(x)=f(\xi)$.

In a similar way one proves that $\lim_{x\to \xi+} f(x)=f(\xi)$ for all $\xi\in S\setminus\{3\}$.

Since all required one-sided limits have the proper value the function $f$ is indeed continuous on $S$.

Comment: We have an example in which $f$ has exactly one discontinuity and you have come up with $f$ being continuous. I am confused sir what should I interpret from this?

Comment: @VikrantDesai: The $f$ you define in a comment is continuous on $S$.

Comment: Oh my god!! It's discontinuous on $\Bbb R$ and I confused it with $S$. Even I had written there that the $f$ turned out to be continuous. But still somehow I pretended that it is discontinuous. Thank you so much Christian!